# Can I use an embedded instance of Ravendb in an Azure Functions application?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, ravendb

I'm 99% sure the answer is "That's dumb, don't do that!" but is it possible/practical to use an embedded instance of RavenDB in an Azure Functions application that shuts down in between calls?

I plan on migrating to a hosted instance of RavenDB by the time my Azure Functions application would need to scale out.